# Angular 6.4.1 configurations not working to replace index.html file

Tags: angular

So trying to do 'ng build --configuration=production' and trying to get it to use the FileReplacements in my angular.json to replace the index.html file under the /src folder with my production version. I see it is replacing the environments ts file correctly.

Using the following versions:

```
"@angular/animations": "^8.0.0-beta.12",
"@angular/cdk": "~7.3.7",
"@angular/common": "^8.0.0-beta.12",
"@angular/compiler": "^8.0.0-beta.12",
"@angular/core": "^8.0.0-beta.12",
"@angular/forms": "^8.0.0-beta.13",
"@angular/material": "^7.3.7",
```

In my regular index.html I have:

```
<base href="/">
```

But in my index.prod.html file I have:

```
<base href="/CSRTest/#/">
```

I am seeing the regular index.html file in my dist folder after building, not the replaced one.

Here is my angular.json snippet:

```
  "configurations": {
    "production": {
      "fileReplacements": [
        {
          "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
          "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
        },
        {
          "replace": "src/index.html",
          "with": "src/index.prod.html"
        }
      ],
      "optimization": true,
      "outputHashing": "all",
      "sourceMap": false,
      "extractCss": true,
      "namedChunks": false,
      "aot": true,
      "extractLicenses": true,
      "vendorChunk": false,
      "buildOptimizer": true,
      "budgets": [
        {
          "type": "initial",
          "maximumWarning": "2mb",
          "maximumError": "5mb"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

If anyone has any ideas how to have a custom index.html file for different environments (prod, qa, etc) would greatly appreciate the help. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I found that putting the environment and index files in separate directories (PRODUCTION, QA, etc) and then doing like this in my angular.json fixed it:

```
  "configurations": {
    "production": {
      "fileReplacements": [
        {
          "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
          "with": "src/environments/PRODUCTION/environment.ts"
        }
      ],
      "index": "src/environments/PRODUCTION/index.html",
```

Then running 'ng build --configuration=production' worked.

Thanks all!

Comment: Thanks a lot. Work to me on angular 6

Answer (score 1):

You can try this workaround to set the `index.html` as an output for your prod environment.

```
"production": {
  "index": {
    "input": "src/index.prod.html",
    "output": "index.html"
  }
}
```

Comment: Tried adding that code above, but getting error:

`hostReportError.js:4    setTimeout(function () ..............`